# Match 2 set or list or dictionary if they share same variable Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find out if `list1` have the same object in `list2` , I shall do something in there, if `list1` doesn't have the same object in `list2` then I shall do other stuff.

What i try to do here is use the if statement as below but fail, no matter list1 has or doesn't have the same object in list2, the coding is still run

```
c = "abc"
a={"abc","dsw","ccc","ddd"}
b={"abc","123"}  
if b.issubset(a):
    do something
else:
    do something
```

I want to compare if either one of the variable inside is the same, or it is repeated.

or is there anyway to compare `c with set like b or a`

subset or superset will only output as True if both set are totally same, I want to check if one or more variables in the set is same or repeated, not necessary all the same.

Comment: Why don't you use `set` operation?: `if list1 & list2: ...` OR `if not list1.isdisjoint(list): ...`

Comment: It prints `No` for me

Comment: what editor are you using and have you imported from numpy import *?

Comment: @user3100115 no it is not.

Comment: @The6thSense sure it is.

Comment: @user3100115 it only say's how to find if a list is in other list. but this problem has more to it check my answer.

Comment: @user3100115 can you help me? if I just want to check either one of the variable is repeated instead of all are the same, question is edited

Comment: is okay i have found a way tq

Answer (score 3):

The main cause would be because you would have imported `from numpy import *`. So when you call the method all you were actually calling [numpy's all method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.all.html)

From it's official document :

> Returns:
>
> > ```
> > all : ndarray, bool
> > ```
> >
> > > A new boolean or array is returned unless out is specified, in which case a reference to out is returned.

The return type of `numpy's all` is an array of boollen.

**Code:**

```
from numpy import *
list1={"abc","dsw","ccc","ddd"}
list2={"abc"}  
print [a for a in all(x i list2 for x in list1)]
```

**Output:**

```
[False, True, False, False]
```

So it your program when you check `if all(x in list2 for x in list1):` it is simplified to `if [False, True, False, False]` which is always `true` because the array is not empty.

to be more clear `if all(x in list2 for x in list1) >> if [False, True, False, False] >> true`

Comment: Why bringing `numpy` into this?

Comment: @user3100115 OP say's it always prints `yes` where as it prints `no` for others. Please run OP's code and see.

Answer (score 2):

As list1 and list 2 are sets, you just can do:

```
print('Yes' if list2.issubset(list1) else 'No')
```

Comment: i have edited my question, can u help me again pls? because if there is any different variable in the set, then the output will be False, What I want is to compare if one of the variable in the set or object is repeated.

Comment: is okay i have found a way tq

Answer (score 2):

You've using sets; there is no need to even use `all` for this:

```
>>> a = {"abc","dsw","ccc","ddd"}
>>> b = {"abc"}
```

You wanted to know if all of the elements in `a` are also in `b`. This means: `a` is subset of `b`:

```
>>> a.issubset(b)
False
>>> b.issubset(a)
True
>>> a.issubset(a)  # is a subset of itself as well = have same elements
True
```

Note that the `issubset` is optimized so that if `b` is a `set` and contains **fewer** elements than `a`, then it can outright return `False`; your method cannot.

Comment: i have edited my question, can u help me again pls? because if there is any different variable in the set, then the output will be False, What I want is to compare if one of the variable in the set or object is repeated.

Comment: is okay i have found a way tq

Answer (score 1):

If list1 and list2 are sets, you will do this(python 2.7):

```
print True if list1 & list2 else False
```